Cypress off auto run in local client
When i go my tests in local browser (cypress open), i'm switching between windows - cypress(chrome), webstoms and my tests started automatically. How can i switch off auto run, and use only CMD + R and CMR + S ??
Change config, thas all

You can change the value of watchForFileChanges in your config to false.

Whether Cypress will watch and restart tests on test file changes. watchForFileChanges is set to true by default during cypress open

You can change that value directly in your configuration file...
module.exports = defineConfig({
  ...
  watchForFileChangs: false,
  ...
})

Or pass in the value when running your cypress open command:
cypress open --config watchForFileChanges=false

